# How to set OneNote link-to-page Shortcut to open in a new window (not an existing one)?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, file-shortcut

I've OneNote link-to-page Shortcut files like these:
[image: OneNote link-to-page Shortcut files]
What I'm looking for is when I open any of these shortcuts, the page will be opened in a new window (not an existing one).

OS: Windows 10 | Office: 2016

---

***Suggested solutions (Not yet solving my question):***

- ***Solution 1:***

> Your shortcut must have the link in this format:
>
> `"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE" /sidenote /hyperlink "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...."`
> Exactly with the quotation marks.
>
> the `onenote:https:...` is the second part of the link provided by
> Onenote when selected the **copy link to page** option

*This solution is very good. But it needs a workaround to make OneNote not to ask me the security confirmation each time I open a shortcut (Like shown in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5oFqK.png)). Also I don't want the notebook to be opened as a side-note such that Tabs and Commands ribbon is not hidden and Page navigation pan also is not like in a side-note.*

Answer (score 2):

There is a crude and awkward way to keep the current page visible while opening the linked page in a new window: Ctrl-m for a copy of the current page, then execute the link on the copied page.

Answer (score 1):

Your shortcut must have the link in this format:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE" /sidenote /hyperlink "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/...."
```

Exactly with the quotation marks.

the `onenote:https:...` is the second part of the link provided by Onenote when selected the **copy link to page** option

Comment: This solution is very good.
But it needs a workaround to make OneNote not to ask me the security confirmation each time I open a shortcut (Like shown in the screenshot https://i.imgur.com/GsO6ITq.png).
Also I don't want the notebook to be opened as a side-note such that Tabs and Commands ribbon is not hidden and Page navigation pan also is not like in a side-note.

Answer (score 0):

Some dirty solution for local notebooks (at least for Win8.1 & OneNote 2013):

We can get the dirty link, something like:

> onenote:#blablabla&section-id={F25AE932-082B-4B58-B818-25BBC7804DD9}&page-id={7E6ACA4E-BA6F-45BA-ACD0-D001F311D1A2}&end&base-path=C:\blabla\blaOneNote\blaBook\blaSection\blablapage.one

Our goal is to extract and execute a link, that looks like:

> onenote:///C:\&section-id={F25AE932-082B-4B58-B818-25BBC7804DD9}&page-id={7E6ACA4E-BA6F-45BA-ACD0-D001F311D1A2}&end

#### BONUS: "How to open on page link in a new window by mouse-button?"

[PowerPro](http://powerpro.cresadu.com) macros for "right double anywhere" (over the link):

```
keys {esc}
wait.for(1) 
keys ^m     ; ctrl+m - onenote "new window" hotkey
wait.for(5) 
keys {enter}
```