# Create shortcut from a link to a specific paragraph in OneNote document: the URL seems too long for a shortcut

Tags: path, shortcuts, microsoft-onenote, file-shortcut

I am using the OneNote version with Office 365 for Windows. OneNote has long allowed users to generate links to specific paragraphs. When these links appear in other OneNote documents or in Word documents, clicking them opens OneNote and takes the user to the designated paragraph. For reference, the links have this form:

```
onenote:#MY%20PAGE&section-id={7B5576B7-19C9-4E1E-AC9D-14FAC5EB2665}&page-id={8A60F88C-65F7-4855-B015-74D37B6D0809}&object-id={4E733586-91E4-06C1-0A43-F8FEAD98545F}&20&base-path=https:XXXX/General.one
```

I have replaced some of these URLs with `XXXX`; in reality, the link is 280 characters long.

I want to create a Windows shortcut that takes me to a specific paragraph, but it seems that Windows can't account for shortcut "Targets" that are longer than [260 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970075/do-windows-shortcuts-support-very-long-argument-lengths). The link indicates that VBS can be used to get around the 260-character limit. But is there another way?

I've searched other posts on this forum but found nothing that speaks to this problem. The most relevant post is probably [How to set OneNote link-to-page Shortcut to open in a new window (not an existing one)?](https://superuser.com/questions/1125372/how-to-set-onenote-link-to-page-shortcut-to-open-in-a-new-window-not-an-existin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried the following and it seems to work. Not sure if my machine/OneNote has any specific configuration which makes this possible, but maybe it's worth a try.

1. Go to the OneNote paragraph you want link to, right click on it and press "Copy Link to Paragraph". I get two lines of text in my clipboard: one starts with `https://tenant.sharepoint.com/...` and the other starts with `onenote:https://tenant.sharepoint.com/...`.
2. Create an empty plain text file and name it however you want, but change the extension to `.url`. For the sake of this example I assume it's named `onenotelink.url`.
3. In the file write the following:

   ```
   [InternetShortcut]
   URL=onenote:https://tenant.sharepoint.com/...
   ```
4. Save the file.
5. If I now doubleclick on `onenotelink.url` OneNote opens on the paragraph I targeted in step 1.